# How to stack QT Charts legend items vertical on bottom

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I need the legend items stacked one above another (vertically).

When I do:

```
QtCharts::QChart *m_pieChart; //member variable
m_pieChart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
```

I get this:

[image: legend items stacked vertically on the right side]

And setting the alignment to bottom moves the legend to the bottom:

```
m_pieChart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
```

BUT the legend items are not stacked vertically anymore!

[image: legend items horizontalle under the chart]

How to move the legend to the bottom AND have them stacked vertically?

Comment: Looking in the sources, starting [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtcharts.git/tree/src/charts/legend/legendlayout.cpp#n121), it doesn't seem possible without modifying Qt's code

Comment: Should I remove the legend completely from the chart and just add a QVBoxLayout with QLabels in it?

Comment: It works, but it does not look good...
http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2mj2.png

Comment: Why don't you use the `detachFromChart()`? Look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-legend-example.html)

Comment: I solved it differently using `QPieSlice::setLabelVisible(true)` on all slices.